# Finding Orthogonal Trajectories (differential equations)

Tags: differential

Find the set of orthogonal functions on the function
$$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}=C(xy)^2$$ where C is non zero.

What I tried doing was first multiplying both sides with $xy$ to get $x^2+y^2=Cx^3y^3$ and now I derived both sides to get

$$2x+2yy'=3C(x^2y^3+x^3y^2y')$$

and by grouping the parts with $y'$ we get 
$$y'(3Cx^3y^2-2y)=2x-3Cx^2y^3$$

here I try to eliminate C by putting $C=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^3y^3}$ and i get 
$$y'(\frac{3(x^2+y^2)x^3y^2}{x^3y^3}-2y)=2x-\frac{3(x^2+y^2)x^2y^3}{x^3y^3}$$
canceling out i get 
$$y'(\frac{3(x^2+y^2)}{y}-2y)=2x-\frac{3(x^2+y^2)}{x}$$ Multiplying by $xy$ i get 
$$y'(3(x^2+y^2)x-2y^2x)=2x^2y-3(x^2+y^2)y$$
Now I know I have to replace $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$with $-\frac{dx}{dy}$

So now I have 
$$\frac{-dx}{dy}(3(x^2+y^2)x-2y^2x)=2x^2y-3(x^2+y^2)y$$

and i'm not sure how to go on from here.

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me from here on out. Or show me an alternate way of doing this

Comment: This seems like a homogeneous equation . Try substituting $$x=vy$$ .

Comment: Thanks. Completrly forgot to check that. . .